# matplotlib 3D scatter animation

Tags: python, matplotlib, animation, plot, visualization

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(100)
y = np.arange(100)
for t in range(100):
    z = np.ones(100)*t
fig = plt.figure(dpi=1200)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')
ax.scatter(x,y,z)
```

I would like to plot in a animation plot depending on `t`. for example  first plot `(x[0], y[0], z)` when t = 0. And then  `(x[1], y[1],z)` when t = 1, etc. **However, the previous points disappear once the new points shows.** May I ask how I can achieve that please? Thank you.
Also , if I  change  `ax.scatter` to `ax.plot_surface`, how would I achieve the same stuff please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I re-structured your code in order to play the animation.
First of all, you need to define a function `update` where the things you want to change from one frame to the next will be updated. In our case, in the `update` function I update `x`, `y` and `z` coordinates based on `t` parameter. Then I clear the previuos plot and plot a new one with updated coordinates. Finally it is convenient to set axes limits, in order to keep the animation frame fixed.

```
def update(t):
    ax.cla()

    x = np.cos(t/10)
    y = np.sin(t/10)
    z = 5

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s = 100, marker = 'o')

    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_zlim(-1, 10)
```

Then you create a figure and a `FuncAnimation` instance, to which you pass the figure over which play the animation, the `update` function and other important parameters, as the number of frames, the interval between them and so on. Refer to the [documentation](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html) for more information.

```
fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = update, frames = 100, interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

### Complete Code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def update(t):
    ax.cla()

    x = np.cos(t/10)
    y = np.sin(t/10)
    z = 5

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s = 100, marker = 'o')

    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_zlim(-1, 10)


fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = update, frames = 100, interval = 100)

plt.show()
```

[image]

---

If you also want to keep track of the particle trajectory, you can add `X`, `Y` and `Z` list in which to save particle coordinates:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


X = []
Y = []
Z = []


def update(t):
    ax.cla()

    x = np.cos(t/10)
    y = np.sin(t/10)
    z = t/10

    X.append(x)
    Y.append(y)
    Z.append(z)

    ax.scatter(x, y, z, s = 100, marker = 'o')
    ax.plot(X, Y, Z)

    ax.set_xlim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_ylim(-2, 2)
    ax.set_zlim(-1, 10)


fig = plt.figure(dpi=100)
ax = fig.add_subplot(projection='3d')

ani = FuncAnimation(fig = fig, func = update, frames = 100, interval = 100, repeat = False)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. May I ask how would it work if t is function itself?

Comment: You should implement it inside `update`. What does `t` depend on? How does `t` change from frame to frame?

Comment: Oh I think I understand what you are saying now. Thanks a lot. I will try myself.